# SimpleDateFormat and TimeZone format

Tags: java

I am trying to make the SimpleDateFormat class to do what I need without success.

Here is the date format I need:

```
Fri 29 May 2015 10:22:30 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)
```

Here is the closest format definition I was able to come with:

```
SimpleDateFormat("EEE dd MM yyyy HH:mm:ss Z (zzzz)", Locale.ENGLISH)
```

This will output:

```
Fri 29 May 2015 10:22:30 -0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)
```

Is there a formatting that can do what I need or do I have no other choice than manipulating the String to insert the missing GMT tag?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add the literal `GMT` surrounded by quotes:

```
new SimpleDateFormat("EEE dd MM yyyy HH:mm:ss 'GMT'Z (zzzz)", Locale.ENGLISH);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `EEE dd MM yyyy HH:mm:ss zZ (zzzz)`

**[Working example](http://ideone.com/ml5Ici)**

Comment: Sorry, that will give you "EDT-0400" not "GMT-0400" at the end.

Comment: @user2656928 I just tried it and it gives me GMT. [Here](http://ideone.com/ml5Ici)'s a working example.

Comment: I run your program and get EDT. Is your system default timezone GMT by any chance? But then you wouldn't get "-0400" afterward.

Comment: @user2656928, this was my output : `Fri 29 05 2015 21:24:03 GMT+0000 (Greenwich Mean Time)`

Comment: Right. So your default timezone is GMT, which is "+0000" from GMT (since it *is* GMT). If you had gotten "GMT-0400" then something would have been very screwy. The OP appears to be running in EDT (as I am), but wants 'GMT' stuck in front of the "-0400" timezone offset (since that's what the offset is relative to). Hence using "z" won't work - it'll provide the local timezone, which is not what the offset relates to.

Comment: @user2656928, Ah, I see. Thanks for clarifying that. Short of throwing in the 'GMT' string literal, I can't think of a way to do this then.

Answer (score 0):

## *java.time*

I recommend you use the [modern date-time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-date-time.html)<sup>*</sup>.

Using the [available symbols](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html), the closest match can be obtained with the pattern, `EEE dd MMM uuuu HH:mm:ss OOOO (zzzz)`. However, it will display a `:` as the separator in the timezone offset. If you want the exact format, you can use the pattern, `EEE dd MMM uuuu HH:mm:ss 'GMT'XX (zzzz)` in which `GMT` has been used as a `String` literal.

**Demo:**

```
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.LocalTime;
import java.time.Month;
import java.time.ZoneId;
import java.time.ZonedDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.util.Locale;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.of(LocalDate.of(2015, Month.MAY, 29), LocalTime.of(10, 22, 30),
                ZoneId.of("America/New_York"));

        DateTimeFormatter dtf1 = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("EEE dd MMM uuuu HH:mm:ss OOOO (zzzz)", Locale.ENGLISH);
        String formatted1 = dtf1.format(zdt);
        System.out.println(formatted1);

        DateTimeFormatter dtf2 = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("EEE dd MMM uuuu HH:mm:ss 'GMT'XX (zzzz)", Locale.ENGLISH);
        String formatted2 = dtf2.format(zdt);
        System.out.println(formatted2);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
Fri 29 May 2015 10:22:30 GMT-04:00 (Eastern Daylight Time)
Fri 29 May 2015 10:22:30 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)
```

Learn more about the the [modern date-time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-date-time.html)<sup>*</sup> from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

---

<sup>* For any reason, if you have to stick to Java 6 or Java 7, you can use [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) which backports most of the *java.time* functionality to Java 6 & 7. If you are working for an Android project and your Android API level is still not compliant with Java-8, check [Java 8+ APIs available through desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) and [How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project).</sup>

Comment: Just because you post an answer using `java.time` (which I think is appropriate, we hsould push towards using modern APIs) doesn't mean the *question* is related to `java.time`. I've undone the re-tagging.

Comment: @JoachimSauer - That was not the reason why I added the tag, `java.time`; I added this tag to make it easier for someone searching for this type of Q/A using the tag, `java-time`. Nevertheless, you have 10 more years of experience on SO than I have and therefore you know much more than I do.